# Selected Index Changed Event Firing when it's not supposed to

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just encountered a strange situation with an ASP.NET page.  My form has 2 controls that have `AutoPostBack="true"`: a `RadioButtonList` and a `DropdownList`.  The RadioButtonList also has `EnableViewState="False"`.  When I change the selected item of the dropdownlist, the `RadioButtonList` `SelectedIndexChanged` event fires as well.  If I remove `EnableViewState="False"`, then this behavior goes away.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?  I have included sample code below so you can see this behavior for yourself:

```
<div>                
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="false" runat="server">            
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="3" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="3" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />              
</div>
```

Here is the code behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rblTest.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    protected void rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text += "RadioButton List SelectedIndexChanged fired<br />";
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text += "Submit Button Click Event Fired<br />";
    }

    protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text += "Dropdown List SelectedIndexChanged Event Fired<br />";
    }
```

Additionally, if you comment out this line in the code behind:

```
rblTest.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Then this behavior does not occur **until** you select something from the radio button list.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you set EnableViewState to false, it means you are not gonna keep the state of the objects. This means that when you do an autopost, the values are reset to their original values.

When it is a post back, you are changing the state of a radio button (rblTest.SelectedIndex = 0) and that's firing the event. So, you change one radio button and 2 events are fired.

Just something else to point out, remember that every time you do a postback, the page is recreated at server-side. And the life-cycle of the page is executed. The ViewState is used on that process to populate the controls. You can read more about it on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply - actually the test code only sets rblTest.SelectedIndex = 0 if it is not a postback - so this would only affect it the first time around.  My point is that if I change a dropdown value, the radio button event gets fired.  It seems like because the viewstate is turned off for the radio button, the event becomes cached and keeps firing when any other event fires.  This does not seem like correct behavior to me.

Comment: But you said that if you remove rblTest.SelectedIndex=0 the problem disappears. Could you please add a breakpoint on that line of code and confirm when it is being executed?

Comment: No, the problem does not disappear.  If you comment out rblTest.SelectedIndex = 0, then the problem does not occur until you select a different radio button.  Once you do this, the radio button event continues to fire even when other events are fired, such as the dropdownlist event.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Probably, after you submit the form the value for the radio button has changed for some reason. Please try to set a default value for the radio button and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I added Selected="True" for the first item in the radiobutton list and the behavior disappears.  So it appears that when you select an item from the radio button list, the value gets cleared on every postback and this triggers the selectedindexchanged event of the radiobutton list.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. It's good that you are developing an ASP.NET MVC WebForms application without ViewState but I must ask, would don't you migrate to ASP.NET MVC so you get rid of ViewState and C# events? life is much cleaner in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `selectedindexchanged` event was firing also when I was not expecting it. What my code did was change the selected value on `selectedindexchange` event. So, next time when a postback occured, the `selectedindexchange` event was also fired again. I solved it by first setting the `selectedindex` to `-1` and then setting the actual value.

Initial code was -

```
protected void rbl_selectedindexchanged(object sender, event evt)
{
rbl.Items.FindByText("something").Selected = true;
}
```

After modify -

```
protected void rbl_selectedindexchanged(object sender, event evt)
{
rbl.SelectedIndex = -1;
rbl.Items.FindByText("something").Selected = true;
}
```